# DensityPlot for function defined via preimage of region

Tags: plotting, regions, visualization

I have a set of functions of two variables, which are defined via a coordinate change. Now I want to visualize them on the image of the coordinates. I can do this in 3D with ParametricPlot3D:

```
x =   1/3 ( 
 Exp[2 Pi I #[[1]]] + Exp[2 Pi I #[[2]]] + 
  Exp[-2 Pi I (#[[1]] + #[[2]])]) &; 
y = 1/3 ( 
 Exp[- 2 Pi I #[[1]]] + Exp[-2 Pi I #[[2]]] + 
  Exp[2 Pi I (#[[1]] + #[[2]])]) &;
xr = 1/2 ( x @ {#1, #2} + y @ {#1, #2}) &;
yr = 1/(2 I ) ( x@ {#1, #2} - y @ {#1, #2}) &;
T[n_, m_] := 
1/6 ( Exp[ 2 Pi I (m #1 - n #2)] +  Exp[ 2 Pi I (-n #1 + m #2)] + 
  Exp[2 Pi I ((m + n) #1 + n #2)] + 
  Exp[ 2 Pi I (n #1 + (n + m) #2)] + 
  Exp[ 2 Pi I ((-n - m) #1 - m #2)] + 
  Exp[ 2 Pi I (-m #1 - (n + m) #2)]) &;
ParametricPlot3D[{Re[xr[u, v]], Re[yr[u, v]], Re[T[2, 0][u, v]]}, {u, 
0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

But I would prefer a 2D density plot. I can not use regions, as I do not want to calculate the inverse map of the coordinate change. What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `ColorFunction` with your `ParametricPlot3D` to get the density plot look, and drop the z cooordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ColorFunction` option to [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) for this:

```
ParametricPlot[{Re[xr[u, v]], Re[yr[u, v]]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, Hue@Re[T[2, 0][u, v]]], 
 PlotPoints -> 30]
```

By using two coordinates as the arguments to `RegionPlot`, you get the desired deltoid area. Then the function `Re@T` is encoded in  `ColorFunction`. To get a better quality display, it may be necessary to add `MaxRecursion -> 4`

This yields the following:

[image]

Comment: This one seems to be perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just drop the z-function:

```
DensityPlot[{Re[xr[u, v]], Re[yr[u, v]]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Something like this?

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Re[xr[u, v]], Re[yr[u, v]], Re[T[2, 0][u, v]]}, {u, 
  0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Comment: No I want the z-values to be displayed as density in the image of the maps xr[u,v], yr[u,v] (a deltoid). So the function to be displayed is T[n,m] and the coordinates are xr, yr.

Comment: Yes the modified answer would be fine :) I did not accept this as an answer, as the one of Jens is nicer, and I can only accept one, but yours is also good.